# Install Libomp - Homebrew is not being found on my terminal

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

Im trying to install libomp on my mac using the following command:
brew install libomp

But everytime I get an error like this:

```
Warning: No available formula with the name "libomp".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
Error: No formulae or casks found for libomp.
```

I already uninstall and install Homebrew twice, uninstall/install and updated the lightgbm package, and nothing seems to work.
I was able to install other packages so is not a problem with my computer or anything like that.

Does anyone know how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following to ensure your Homebrew is up to date.

```bash
brew update
```

Then install `libomp` like this

```bash
brew install libomp
```

> and updated the lightgbm package

I'm not sure if this means the `lightgbm` Python package, the `lightgbm` CLI installed via Homebrew, or something else...but either way, the presence of those things should not impact whether or not Homebrew is able to install `libomp` on your system.

Comment: Thanks, I followed the steps you mentioned but it did not work, Im still getting the same message as before.

Comment: Sad to hear it! If you can post more logs, how you installed homebrew, you macOS version you might get a more helpful answer. I suspect there's something non-standard about your setup, but can't tell based on the information provided so far.

Comment: I was able to fix it. Update my macOS version, uninstall and install again and it worked!

Comment: Great, glad it is working for you.